# Nextjs Bootstrap is Overriding CSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning react and nextjs, and am faced with a problem where the bootstrap css is overriding my own css.

Here is my code

index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Navbar from "../components/PrimaryBtn";

export default () => (
<div>
<Head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
</Head>
<PrimaryBtn color="blue">click<PrimaryBtn />
</div>
);
```

PrimaryBtn.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './PrimaryBtn.css';

export default const PrimaryBtn = (props) => {
return (
<div>
<button className={`btn btn-primary ${styles[props.color]}`}>{props.children}</button>
</div>
);
}
```

PrimaryBtn.css

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This background-color is overridden by the bootstrap class because the bootstrap cdn is rendered after my styles is there any work around to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I fix it by changing the import of the bootstrap.
Instead of importing this: `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`
I import the Bootsrap CSS in the Head of `_app.js` like:

```
<Head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </Head>
```

[code screen shot for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPZjy.png)

Comment: What if I have newly App router, where I don't have _app.js and if I import this into layout.js there my css order in correct order, meaning, bootstrap classes are not overriding with my custom css.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put a `console.log(styles)` in your `PrimaryBtn` render function, I assume you would see `null` or `undefined`. CSS is not understood by JavaScript, importing it into your JavaScript code only serves the purpose of ensuring that Webpack (or similar) includes it in your bundle. You only need to include the name of your class in your `className`, I believe `` className={`btn btn-primary ${props.color}`} `` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats not the problem. i have used module css which changes my class name and styles will contain my changed class name.